# Create map of frost free days using Daymet data in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf, climate

I stumbled on DAYMET today for creating graphs in R for frost free days at a given location. This was all using boiler plate code someone in my agency made where you just change lat/long; I'm an R and python idiot.

I was wondering if there is a way within Arcmap itself where I can get the consecutive frost free days for each year out of the netCDF files, then create contour lines or just a shapefile with the different bands of FFDs averaged out from 1980-2018. When I search similar ideas, most of them involve R, Python, or google earth engine. Is there an Arc exclusive way to do this?